# Foreign character encoding issue with CSV download

Tags: utf-8, vbscript, character-encoding

I am using UTF8 encoding for ASP pages. I want to implement a CSV download functionality for my website. Below is my response setup

```
With Response
    .Buffer = true
    .Expires = 0
    .Clear
    .Charset = "UTF-8"
    .CodePage = 65001
    .AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
    .AddHeader "content-encoding", "UTF-8"
    .AddHeader "content-disposition", "attachment; filename=""AgedDebtors.csv"""
End With
```

Encoding is set for response headers still i am getting encoded foreign characters in resulting CSV. Tried few things for this but was not able to get it right. Please let me know what i am missing here

Comment: "I want to implement a CSV download functionality for my website" Good for you. Now, what's the actual problem you're asking about?

Comment: @Danack: i have specifically mentioned it dude....please read it carefully.

Comment: "Please let me know what i am missing here" Is not an acceptable question.
http://sscce.org/ You don't actually say what you're getting, compared to what you're exepecting. "i am getting encoded foreign characters" is a meaningless phrase and doesn't actually describe what you're seeing. Also, you aren't showing any code for where you're actually generating the CSV file or, or how it's being sent to the output. The question you meant to ask is something like "How do I correctly send a CSV to the output?" with an example bit of data, rather than just "what am I missing".

Answer (score 0):

```
  Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  stream.Open
  stream.Type     = 2 'text
  stream.Position = 0
  stream.Charset  = "utf-8"
  stream.WriteText str
```

you may want to save the converted stream into a new file, so write this

```
  stream.SaveToFile filename, 2
```

And to close the stream use

```
  stream.Close
```